# Redis HGET is consuming too much of time

Tags: magento2, cache, redis

One of my client M2 store is using Redis for session and cache storage.
On inspecting the New Relic, have noticed that `HGET` is consuming hell lot of time
[image: Redis HGET]

Redis Configuration:

- Local Redis connected with TCP
- Setting: `maxmemory-policy allkeys-lru`

How do you guys optimize the Redis (single instance) for your M2 store?

Answer (score 1):

Magento >= 2.3.5 have a preload functionality that allows to load multiple keys by one request.

See https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/redis/redis-pg-cache.html#redis-preload-feature for more details

Works especially well with two level cache https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/cache/two-level-cache.html

Comment: That's a good point but unfortunately store is operating on version < 2.4.0

Comment: You can back port cache adapter to your version (just copy/past ;)

Comment: You mean just to udpate the Redis module from M 2.4?

Comment: Just add https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.4-develop/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Cache/Backend/Redis.php file

Comment: Is anyone found solution for this issue?